# Angular Service Error not returning the control to then

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a question regarding angular service. I have a controller and a service and if in service(which is calling a backend code) and  I get an error. It is not transferring the control back to controller as if not returning a response.
How can I solve it

service call in controller

```
myservice.saveChange(data).then(function(data){
console.log(data);
//some Code
}
```

my service

```
this.myresp = function(obj){ $http.post(url,obj).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
               this.resp = data;
}).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
this.resp = data;
})
return this.myresp;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain this using the relevant code. Also no idea what *"transferring the control back to controller"* means exctly

Comment: @charlietfl The problem is I want to close a pop up based on a error but the control is stuck in the error part it is not returning anything else I also tried placing the return in error block but still no resolution

Comment: you aren't returning the data in the service. Need to use `then()` not `success` or `error` and return the data

Comment: @charlietfl thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a promise takes in 2 callbacks a `success` and a `fail`
. You can return your error from the second callback

```
$http.get('url').then(
    function(){return 'success';}, 
    function(){return 'error'});
```

Don't know if this can help you because you did not include any code